# Subtract by 20 till the value reaches 0 and add from and to to object of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, ecmascript-6

Say I have a `value:-100`. I want to subtract by 25 and add it to an object of arrays in this format:

```
arr = [{start: -100, end: -75}, {start: -75, end: -50}, {start: -50, end: -25}, {start: -25, end: 0}]
```

I want to subtract the beginning value by 25 till we reach 0.

I tried something like this:

```js
const getAllNumbersBetween = (x, y, subBy) => {
        var numbers = [];  
        for (var i = x; i < y; i++) {
            let obj = {};
            obj['start'] = i;
            obj['end'] = i+subBy;
            numbers.push(obj);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

console.log(getAllNumbersBetween(-100, 0, 25));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I run this function I am getting 100 results. `start` always is just subtracting by `1`.

How do I get my data to look like this:

`arr = [{start: -100, end: -75}, {start: -75, end: -50}, {start: -50, end: -25}, {start: -25, end: 0}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close. Just change `i++` into `i += subBy` in your for loop like this:

```js
const getAllNumbersBetween = (x, y, subBy) => {
  var numbers = [];
  for (var i = x; i < y; i += subBy) {
    let obj = {};
    obj['start'] = i;
    obj['end'] = i + subBy;
    numbers.push(obj);
  }
  return numbers;
}

console.log(getAllNumbersBetween(-100, 0, 25));
```